# Criar Projeto de DLL

Tags: c, dll

Estou tentando trabalhar com XFS, porém na documentação pede para criar uma DLL para cada serviço, porém as dll's não vem na api, elas devem ser construidas, só que na instalação do ambiente só tem arquivos .h, iguais a este [aqui](https://github.com/chopengauer/wosa_ncr/blob/master/XFSDispense/SDK/INCLUDE/XFSSPI.H).

Sei que são arquivos de cabeçalho em C. Quero saber como faço para transforma-los em DLL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não "transforma" os cabeçalhos em C. Esses cabeçalhos são apenas "declarações", não são código executável.

Se você está criando um service provider wosa/xfs, sua missão é criar uma DLL que **implemente** as declarações que estão no cabeçalho. **Você** é que vai criar o código executável em C para cada função declarada no arquivo xfsspi.h.

Se você é um usuário e está desenvolvendo uma aplicação wosa/xfs para um dispositivo wosa/xfs da NCR (o que parece ser o caso) então **seu fornecedor (NCR) deve providenciar as DLLS wosa/xfs** para seus dispositivos (dispensador de notas, recebedor, etc).